# how to move a image when i drag the other image in the other canvas at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to handle two canvases. I also set two canvases to compare two images in a same page.

like this:

`<canvas id="firstImg" width="843" height="1200"></canvas>
<canvas id="secondImg" width="843" height="1200"></canvas>`

I want to move a image when i drag the other image in the other canvas.

I mean when I drag a image to change the position in firstImg canvas, I also move the other image in secondImg canvas at same time.

Is it possible??

Comment: Read the x/y properties from the object you are moving, apply (set) them  on the (replicated) object on the second canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this?

I've made a simple function to draw an image on a canavs. When you drag the image you simply call the function for both canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/96rdnv3L/

```js
var canvasOne = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var ctxOne = canvasOne.getContext("2d");

var canvasTwo = document.getElementById("canvasTwo");
var ctxTwo = canvasTwo.getContext("2d");

var mouseX=0;
var mouseY=0;
var imageX=0;
var imageY=0;
var drag = false;
canvasOne.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){drag=true;}, false);
canvasOne.addEventListener("mouseup",  function(){drag=false;}, false);
canvasOne.addEventListener("mousemove", moveImage, false);

var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "http://home.niddro.com/HTML5/flxprt/img/logo_orange_small.png";

function moveImage(event) {
    if (drag) {
        var x = new Number();
        var y = new Number();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
    
        if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined)
        {
          x = event.x;
          y = event.y;
        }
        else // Firefox method to get the position
        {
          x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
              document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
          y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
              document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
    
        x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
        y -= canvas.offsetTop;
        var deltaX = mouseX-x;
        var deltaY = mouseY-y;
        drawImage(imageX-deltaX,imageY-deltaY,ctxOne,canvasOne,myImage);
        drawImage(imageX-deltaX,imageY-deltaY,ctxTwo,canvasTwo,myImage);
        
    }
}

drawImage(imageX,imageY,ctxOne,canvasOne,myImage);
drawImage(imageX,imageY,ctxTwo,canvasTwo,myImage);


function drawImage(x,y,ctx,canvas,img) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="300"></canvas><br />
<canvas id="canvasTwo" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```